# Scala copy constructor on generic class appears to lose kind on convenience method - why?

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion

I have the following in a codebase:

```
case class QueryOptions[T] private (
    range: DateRange,
    key: T,
    strategy: KeyStrategy,
    interval: Long,
    limit: Int
) {
  def withRange(newRange: DateRange) = copy(range = newRange)
}
```

I can see both from type inference expectations and from my IDE that the call to copy is returning a QueryOptions[T]. However, the method withRange is returning a QueryOptions[Nothing]. Obviously I can apply typing to it to force the result to QueryOptions[T]) and it compiles just fine; why would Scala not understand here that, if A = B, type[A] = type[B]?

Comment: How would I reproduce this on my own machine? I don't have your `DateRange` and `KeyStrategy` classes. When I attempted to reproduce it without them, I didn't get the behavior you describe: https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/c0b9b174ae5b051a5d69

Comment: Interesting. I just used

    case class QueryOptions[T] private (
        range: String,
        key: T,
        interval: Long,
        limit: Int
    ) {
      def withRange(newRange: String) = copy(range = newRange)
    }

and got exactly the same issue.

Comment: Are we using the same Scala version? I'm on 2.11.7. Maybe post a REPL transcript like mine, showing precisely what you tried?

Comment: Yep, 2.11.7. But it's not so much the type at run time I'm worried about, it's the inferred type. Yours gets around this because there's no requirement on your second line. Try doing something like val res: C[String] = C("foo", 5).foo - that's a compilation failure for me. IntelliJ flags it and SBT won't build it without explicitly typing the withRange method. I'll admit to not having tried it in REPL, but don't know what the difference could be.

Comment: I have revised the gist as you suggest — still no compilation error at my end.